# nodejs get version of executable

Tags: node.js, windows

I'd like to know how to use Node.js to get the AssemblyVersion or AssemblyFileVersion of a windows executable.

I'm not sure if it matters, but the executable in question is a .net executable.

I'm happy to use a slim third party dependency, if needed.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I can use the command on windows wmic like so:

`wmic datafile where name='file/program.exe' get version`

Which will print a standard string like this:

```
Version
2.0.1.0
```

which can be easily parsed by splitting on the new line and trimming.

So what I do is promisify the exec call like so:

```
PromiseExec(`wmic datafile where name='${queryPath}' get version`)
.then(exeVersion => {
    let versionSplit = exeVersion.stdout.split('\n');
    let versionString = versionSplit[1].trim(); // "2.0.1.0"
});


/**
 * @param {string} app command to execute
 * @returns {Promise<{stdout:string, stderr:string, code:number}>}
 */
function PromiseExec(app) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let child = exec(app);
        let stdout = '';
        let stderr = '';

        child.addListener('error', reject);

        child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
            stdout += data;
        });

        child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
            stderr += data;
        });

        child.addListener('close', (code) => {
            resolve({ stdout, stderr,  code} );
        });
    });
}
```

Note I've removed some of the error checking for clarity.

Comment: looked promising but couldn't get the wmic part to work, I always get error "no instance available".